# Where is Password for iOS Keychain unlock stored

Tags: ios, encryption, keychain

As we know OS X needs master password to unlock keychain and decrypt all data that is stored there. In general master password is stored in user's brains so there no any direct IT ways to compromise this password.
At the same time iOS makes some simplifications and it doesn't require master password that known only by user. So I became interested how is logic for iOS keychain unlocking and data decrypting implemented and found such explanation in Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9):

> In iOS, an application always has access to its own keychain items and
>   does not have access to any other application’s items. **The system
>   generates its own password for the keychain, and stores the key on the
>   device in such a way that it is not accessible to any application**.

As I understand iOS generates master password by itself and stores it in some specific place.

**My question is:** does anybody know or have any ideas what is it place or way that used for storing master password that guarantees preventing from any IT attacks or third party accesses?

(I found some similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900384/where-is-the-keychain-data-stored), but there are no any specific information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of information in the [Apple iOS Security Whitepaper](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Security_Feb14.pdf)

Essentially the passcode is "tangled" with a device specific ID that is not available to executing code in order to generate keys.  The keys used to unlock files and the keychain are kept in memory while the phone is unlocked (or after first unlock for some protection classes) but are discarded on lock or reboot (again depending on the protection classes) but the passcode itself is never stored in memory or a code accessible file system.